# How do I import a new code style scheme to IntelliJ IDEA for JavaScript or other languages?

Tags: intellij-idea, settings

When I view JavaScript code in IntelliJ Community it isn't formatted or coloured in any way

[image: not my code]

and when I look at the languages listed under Settings|Editor|Code Style I'm missing JavaScript from the list of supported languages but i've definitely seen it in this list before.

[image]

How can I import JavaScript or other languages in so I can make it look better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you are using Community Edition of Intellij IDEA which is not supporting JavaScript as can be seen [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/#section=windows), thus the solution is *to update to Ultimate*, then your JavaScript code will be highlighted.